# .htaccess : set php_value based on incoming REQUEST_URI

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to set a specific `php_value` in htaccess based on an incoming `REQUEST_URI`. I see in Apache 2.4 that there are conditional blocks, but we're using `2.2`, so is there a way to achieve this?

Ex:

I want to set `php_value memory_limit 64M` ONLY when the incoming URI matches a pattern of `'/batch-process'`   otherwise it will always be 32M

Currently I am able to get `mod_rewrite` to check the `request_uri` and set an env variable, but I am missing how to read this in the htaccess file and then set the `php_value` based on that.

Is this possible?

My current htaccess rules are:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/berightback.html -f
RewriteRule !^(css|js|img|berightback\.html) /berightback.html [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d 
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

This is what I ended up doing. Please comment if there was any other way.

In the php.ini file, I bumped the memory_limit to 256M
Then on the index.php page, I checked the incoming REQUEST_URI for the '/batch-process' and if NOT THERE, did an ini_set of memory_limit back down to 32M

Doesnt seem ideal, but could not get this to function otherwise on the large batch-process requests.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you map to your front controller. If you're doing it via rewrite rules then you can use a `<Location>` instead of `<Directory>` block to specify a chunk of path you want to change the settings for. `<LocationMatch>` lets you use a regexp for the same thing

Comment: I updated my question to include my current rewrite conds and rules. I had tried using the <Location> in my vhost but that didnt seem to work either. I had some logging in my index file before anything even loaded, and it never executed. The memory_limit blew out before it even processed.  Will try again.